# Find overlapping date ranges in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, date, indexeddb

I would like to find which date ranges overlaps a period in IndexedDB.

My idea was to store my events in a database, then make a query to get the events which overlap the period range.

Something like the following query (sorry, I don't really remember how to write SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE (startTime BETWEEN periodStart AND periodEnd)
OR 
(periodStart > startDate AND periodStart < endTime)
```

Unfortunately, the only possibility that I found with IndexedDB is to test if a date overlap a range.

For your informations, my events look like the following object:

```
[{
  title: 'foo',
  start: '2013-06-30',
  end: '2013-07-03'
},
{
  title: 'bar',
  start: '2013-07-04',
  end: '2013-07-11'
}]
```

And a period is like:

```
var periodStart = '2013-06-30';
var periodEnd = '2013-07-05';
```

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem.. any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use numeric value of the timestamp?

Comment: Of course I can. But I still can't find which ranges overlap a date range.